# How to monitor engagement via button clicks / purchases

Tags: marketing, statistics, telemetry

I want to measure user engagement:

- Button clicks
- Purchases
- When they view a UI etc

I'd like to know at which point players enter the game and when they're most likely to stop playing.

What are some good ways to measure these things and generate graphs that make this information easy to visualise?

Comment: How comes there's a close vote? Surely metrics are a great tool for game developers?

Comment: The close vote was cast on an earlier version of the question, where it could be interpreted to be asking "what service/library/platform/etc should I use to monitor engagement?" - asking for recommendations for which services/libraries to use is not considered on-topic here. I edited the question to try to make it less about selecting a provider and more about strategies for solving the problem, to hopefully keep the question from being closed.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is to grab a 3rd party library for handling analytics.  There are a lot of great options out there, many of which are free.  Which options you have depends on your platform (mobile, desktop, etc.) and your programming language (C++, C#, etc.).

The way to implement varies based on your library, but they are all roughly the same.

1. Import the library of your choice
2. Link it with their cloud solution
3. Add code to your project where you want the analytics to be called.  For example, on a button press.  The library's documentation will show you the specific code you need to add.
4. Go to the library's website and view your documention.

There are a lot of options to choose from, and it can be overwhelming.  Some of the most reliable and affordable options are owned by major tech companies, so you may want to start there.

Examples include Firebase and PlayFab.

---

You can also write your own analytics tool, and link them to visualizers.  This requires a lot more time and effort, and typically there is a dedicated person/team for writing this visualization.

Examples include Databricks + Tableau.

---

It is important to know what to analyze.  You don't want to track too much, or it will be challenging to filter out important information.  You don't want to track too little, or it won't have enough information.  The best approach is to track too little, and then add information as you need it.  Once you have data in your analytics, its probably there forever.

---

*Disclaimer:  This is very much not my forte.  Any data scientists out there...your answer would be much appreciated.*